# C}++ How to display a vector of objects for the user in a certain format

Tags: c++, string, vector, format, output

Okay so, I've been beating myself up over this and I don't think include all of my code in this post to find an answer. Part of my problem is I don't really know how to word the question.

So say I have a vector of objects called inventory that takes objects from my Item class. and I make a function: `inventory.addItem(itemObject)`

So I can successfully add items just by using the `inventory.push_back(itemObject)` 
function.

When I display the vector I can iterate through it and print out to the console

```
iterator->itemObject.getItemName()
```

But my main goal is to print out that I have multiple of the same objects and print out one of the getItemName and then an integer value of how many of the objects with equal getItemName values and print out that value next to it:

For example:

```
Item hammer("Hammer");  
Item sword("Sword");

inventory.addItem(hammer);  
inventory.addItem(hammer);  
inventory.addItem(hammer);  
inventory.addItem(sword);
```

And if I use my `inventory.displayInventory()` function which all I do is iterate through each object, and access the object's `getItemName()` function and have it be outputted giving me:

```
"Hammer"  
"Hammer"  
"Hammer"  
"Sword"
```

My goal is to have in my `inventory.displayInventory()` function:

```
"Hammer" (3)  
"Sword" (1)
```

Does anyone have any Idea how I can manipulate my for loop iteration to help with this? Or does this sound like a bad idea through and through and I should just stick with them printing separate?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: How about using e.g. [`std::multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) (or possibly [`std::unordered_multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset))? Then you can easily get a [count](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/count) of the "elements".

Comment: A [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) (or its [unordered variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unorderd_map)) could be used as well, with the item as the key and the count as the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) to do this:

```
std::map<std::string, int> items;
for(Item const& item : inventory) {
    items[item.getItemName()]++;
}

for(auto const& pair : items) {
    std::cout << pair.first << ": (" << pair.second << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

If you need the calculation to be more specific than just Item Names, that's possible too, though you need to make sure your `Item` class overloads `operator<` and `operator==`, since `std::map` requires that its keys be sortable. If you've done that, though, then the code is slightly simpler:

```
std::map<Item, int> items;
for(Item const& item : inventory) {
    items[item]++;
}

for(auto const& pair : items) {
    std::cout << pair.first.getItemName() << ": (" << pair.second << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: why not `unordered_map` ?

Comment: @Everyone Because `std::map` is shorter to write, and we don't know that performance is a concern in OP's use-case.

Answer (score 0):

You want a map rather than a vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct Item {
    std::string name;
    Item(std::string name) : name(name){}
    bool operator<(const Item& other) const { return name < other.name;}
};

struct Inventory {
    std::map<Item,size_t> data;
    void addItem(const Item& item){ data[item]++; }
    void print(){
        for (auto e : data){
            std::cout << e.first.name << " (" << e.second << ")\n";
        }
    }

};


int main(){
    Item hammer("hammer");
    Item knife("knife");
    Inventory inventory;
    inventory.addItem(hammer);
    inventory.addItem(hammer);
    inventory.addItem(knife);
    inventory.print();
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/vzkGpI)

`Item` needs a `operator<`, so you can put it in the map. And `data[item]++;` adds the key to the map if it does not exist already (default initializes the count if it didnt exist) and increments the count. Finally printing the inventory can be done with a simple loop.

PS: alternatively you could use a `std::unordered_map` or maybe some other associative container.

Comment: @Everyone "one same key" ? I dont understand